# jQuery's .children() is not a function with jQuery installed

Tags: html, jquery

I want to join nav tabs with enum-based function. I have found a good example of the latter here:
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Switch-Case-with-Enum-in-JavaScript.aspx

but I get either: `children() is not a function` or `siblings() is empty` depending on where I put the function call and the html tags.

The code:

```js
$(function(){
  navTabActivate('one');
});

function navTabActivate(tab){
  $('.nav-tabs a[id="' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};

const TheNumber = {
    "One": 1,
    "Two": 2,
    "Three": 3
  };

var currentNumber = TheNumber.One

function number_switch(no) {
  switch (parseInt(no)) {
    case TheNumber.One:
        console.log("And a one")
      break;
    case TheNumber.Two:
        console.log("And a two")
      break;
    case TheNumber.Three:
        console.log("And a three!")
      break;
    default:
      currentNumber = TheNumber.One;
    };
  };
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="menu">
          <li class="nav-item" onclick="number_switch((this).children('a number'))">
            <a class="nav-link" id="one" data-toggle="tab" number="1">1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" onclick="number_switch((this).children('a number'))">
            <a class="nav-link" id="two" data-toggle="tab" number="2">2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" onclick="number_switch((this).children('a number'))">
            <a class="nav-link" id="three" data-toggle="tab" number="3">3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content menu" style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <p>One</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `(this).children('a number')` does not use jQuery. You probably meant `$(this).children('a number')`

Comment: As an add on to above: You probably want: `number_switch($(this).find("a").attr("number"))`

Comment: Inline JS handler attributes like `onclick` should not be used. Use addEventListener or .on() in jQuery

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please replace code HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="menu">
  <li class="nav-item" onclick="number_switch(this)">
    <a class="nav-link" id="one" data-toggle="tab" number="1">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" onclick="number_switch(this)">
    <a class="nav-link" id="two" data-toggle="tab" number="2">2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" onclick="number_switch(this)">
    <a class="nav-link" id="three" data-toggle="tab" number="3">3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And JS:

```
switch (parseInt(no.outerText)) {

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Thank you. That's the right answer :)